# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jwt"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, jwt

Running bundle or bundle update could not solve the problem. I've tried removing the Gemfile.lock. <del>Seems weird that bundler could not decide that `jwt (~> 2.1)` should satisfy `jwt (~> 1.5)`.</del>

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jwt":
  In Gemfile:
    knock was resolved to 2.1.1, which depends on
      jwt (~> 1.5)

    pusher-chatkit-server (~> 1.1.0) was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
      pusher-platform (~> 0.11.2) was resolved to 0.11.2, which depends on
        jwt (~> 2.1)
```

Comment: `~> 1.5` resolves to `['>= 1.5', '< 1.6']` while `~> 2.1` resolves to `['>= 2.1','< 2.2']`. So, `jwt (~> 2.1)` does not satisfy `jwt (~> 1.5)`.

Comment: BTW, I just glanced at the `pusher-chatkit-server` homepage and it looks like the last version that would be compatible with `jwt (~> 1.5)` is [0.8.2](https://rubygems.org/gems/pusher-platform/versions/0.8.2).